# Python 3: super() raises TypeError unexpectedly

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror, superclass, super

Coming from Java, I'm struggling a bit getting down inheritance, abstract classes, static methods and similar concepts of OO programming in Python.

I have an implementation of an expression tree class, given (simplified) by

```
# Generic node class
class Node(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def to_expr(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def bracket_complex(child):
        s = child.to_expr()
        return s if isinstance(child, Leaf) or isinstance(child, UnaryOpNode) else "(" + s + ")"


# Leaf class - used for values and variables
class Leaf(Node):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_expr(self):
        return str(self.val)


# Unary operator node
class UnaryOpNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, op, child):
        self.op = op
        self.child = child

    def to_expr(self):
        return str(self.op) + super().bracket_complex(self.child)


# Binary operator node
class BinaryOpNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, op, lchild, rchild):
        self.op = op
        self.lchild = lchild
        self.rchild = rchild

    def to_expr(self):
        return super().bracket_complex(self.lchild) + " " + str(self.op) + " " + super().bracket_complex(self.rchild)


# Variadic operator node (arbitrary number of arguments)
# Assumes commutative operator
class VariadicOpNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, op, list_):
        self.op = op
        self.children = list_

    def to_expr(self):
        return (" " + str(self.op) + " ").join(super().bracket_complex(child) for child in self.children)
```

The method `to_expr()` works fine when called on instances of `Leaf`, `UnaryOpNode` and `BinaryOpNode`, but raises a `TypeError` when called on an instance of `VariadicOpNode`:

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

What am I doing wrong in that specific class that `super()` is suddenly not working?

In Java the static method would get inherited so I wouldn't even need the super call, but in Python this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: are you using Python2 or 3? https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Comment: @Jasper Since he is using `super` without arguments he is using python3.3+ I believe.

Comment: Off-topic: why are you using `super()` in `to_expr` to call `bracket_complex`? You should be using `self`, otherwise you risk introducing problems in subclasses that override `bracket_complex`

Comment: As the title states, I'm using Python 3. I have fixed the super() -> self issue after Bakuriu's answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `super()` without arguments in a generator expression. The `super()` is magic - it relies on information in the caller frame. Since the generator expression creates an additional function, `super()` without arguments does not work there. However since your superclass is not probable to change *in the middle of execution of a method*, you can move it out of the generator expression - this should also speed things up:

```
def to_expr(self):
    bracket_complex = super().bracket_complex
    return (" " + str(self.op) + " ").join(bracket_complex(child) for child in self.children)
```

However as static methods are "inherited" in Python, you could call the super method via `self` provided that you didn't override it in a subclass. Thus in this simple case you can write:

```
def to_expr(self):
    return (" " + str(self.op) + " ").join(self.bracket_complex(child) for child in self.children)
```

---

The implementation detail is that if no arguments are provided, the first argument shall be the value that is in the `__class__` cell of the caller frame, and second shall be the first argument given to the caller function. Usually you just get a `SystemError` when using `super` in a wrong place, but generator expressions are wrapped inside an implicit generator function which creates another call frame. Unfortunately this function gets an argument, which leads the `super()` to complain with this exception.

So normally `super()` would be passed `Foo` there as the first argument, but within generator expression, a generator object was passed - and thus it is obvious that `TypeError` needs to be raised.

Answer (score 9):

Answering your implied question:

> In Java the static method would get inherited so I wouldn't even need
>   the super call, but in Python this does not seem to be the case.

`staticmethod`s **are** inherited:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print('Hello')

class B(A):
    def b(self):
        self.a()

b = B()
b.a()
b.b()
```

outputs:

```
Hello
Hello
```

Note that you *cannot* simply write:

```
class B(A):
    def b(self):
        a()
```

Python will **never** resolve a simple name to a method/staticmethod; for Python `a()` *must* be a function call, local or global. You must either reference the instance using `self.a` or the class using `B.a`.

In python the `self` is *explicit* as is the current class reference. Do not confuse with the implicit `this` of Java.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, that makes sense.

Comment: Upvoted :D when debugging the reason behind this phenomenon, I failed to see that the `super()` was unnecessary